# Python unexplained keyword 'sub'

Tags: python

```
def foo(self, sub, **kwargs):
    accounts = kwargs.get('accounts')        
    start    = kwargs.get('start', 0)        
    end      = kwargs.get('end', 0)          
    return json.dumps(                       
        sub(accounts, start, end),           
    )
```

Can you explain, what this 'sub' is and what it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a parameter of the function, and the code expects it to be a callable.

Python functions, methods and objects with a `__call__` method are all callable and could be used to supply `foo` with an argument `sub`.

There is not much else we can say about this without a lot more context.

Comment: Thank you Martijn. Now it makes sense to me. I will I could add to your reputation but I still need 4 more rep to do that. heh..thanks again.

Comment: @KuriousMind: you can accept answers with any reputation, which itself gives you more reputation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I didn't mean to imply there was, but I edited to clarify.

Comment: @martineau: Not sure if I entirely approve of that edit. The OP has, in my opinion, just used the wrong term for a positional parameter, and didn't actually think it was a keyword parameter instead.

Comment: Hard to tell what they were thinking...your call.